# One Physical server, five Redis instances and a requirement to cluster

Tags: redis

We have one physical server to install Redis on, the requirements are that Redis is required for five different applications, each accessible through five ports opened on the firewall.

My understanding is that if we create five individual Redis configs and scripts such as:

- Application 1 = redis.port.6301.config (and associated Redis script
  in etc/init.d)
- Application 2 = redis.port.6302.config (and associated    Redis
  script in etc/init.d)
- Application 3 = redis.port.6303.config    (and associated Redis
  script in etc/init.d)
- Application 4 =    redis.port.6304.config (and associated Redis
  script in etc/init.d)
- Application 5 = redis.port.6305.config (and associated Redis script
  in etc/init.d)

this will allow for five separate instances of Redis to be started. The next part of the Requirement is that Redis be clustered. From reading the Redis Cluster specification and Redis Cluster tuorial.

When the script to create a cluster is run to create a Redis cluster is creates a minimum of six Redis Nodes, three masters and three slaves, each of these require a port in their individual Redis configs. So for redis.port.6301.config, there would be an addition five ports (eg 6311,6321,6331,6341,6351) listening for the other nodes in this cluster.

Following that, it means the 30 ports would be listening on the server.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You probably don't want all those redises sitting in the same basket. what if machine crashes or network goes down.

Comment: I do agree and I understand with what you say, but cost cutting has reduced it to one physical server

Comment: What I mean to say, is what is the purpose of this clustering if it's all on the same machine? It doesn't make much practical sense.

Comment: Its a requirement that I inherited, it makes no practical sense but, it's been agreed, signed off and budgeted for.and a statement of works produced. I've read up on Redis and Redis Cluster and it makes no sense to me, but our "Redis Expert" has stated the above and I'm trying to work it out..

Comment: Well, accepting that, your understanding seems to be correct. If every of 5 redises should be a separate cluster then it'd mean 5xN open ports, where N is number of nodes in a cluster.